# How to make a gem shatter and disintegrate in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want a gem to explode into pieces when the command is given in code, but I can't seem to figure out how to do that. Is there a asset tool I can use in the unity store, or may I be told how to do so? I want the fragments to fly away from each other, then disappear after a few seconds.

Gem image

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Comment: Here is a clue: don't think about how you shatter a gem. Shatter it beforehand. Then all you have to do is to make sure the small pieces are shown and moved once the gem shatters ...

Answer (score 0):

Shatter the 3D Gem Object in a 3D Application as an animation. Maybe 3 or 5 different shatter animations. In Unity, randomly select each shattered animation and play it. Also rotate the Gem while playing the shatter animation. This will make the shattering look random.